# Why Can't Serialized Objects Be Stored in const Constants?

Tags: php, serialization, constants, declaration

```
<?php
    const FOOBAR = "Foo"; // Works.
    const FOOBAR = array("Foo", "Bar"); // Doesn't work.  Makes sense.
    const FOOBAR = serialize(array("Foo", "Bar")); // Doesn't work.  Okay.  :\

    define("FOOBAR", serialize(array("Foo", "Bar"))); // Works!  The heck?
 ?>
```

`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'`

Why can constants be set to serialized objects when they're declared with `define()`, but not  with the `const` keyword?  What am I missing here?

(Tested with `5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2`.)

Comment: Constant declarations (also the ones in global context) can only be values, not expressions. You are not doing an *assignment* there, you are *declaring*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [define() vs const](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447791/define-vs-const) and [Can I use string concatenation to define a class CONST in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786279/can-i-use-string-concatenation-to-define-a-class-const-in-php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

const can only take scalar or non expressions values.

define will take expressions values and that is why define works in your case.

Answer (score 2):

const is a compile-time action. define is a run-time action. More php machinery including array allocation and space allocation is available at runtime.

A related [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447791/define-vs-const)

Google php const define

for more