# How to use a php variable within a define function

Tags: php, variables

I'm trying to add a name into a defined filepath like this -

```
define("theme_name", "andrew");
define("LAYOUT_DIR", ROOT_DIR.'_content/layouts/themes/<?php echo $theme_name;?>/');
```

I get an error that the path does not exist when it is executed but the "andrew" folder does exist.

I tried joining with dots instead of echo and still got this error.

**Full error message**

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Loader' with message 'The "G:\Uwamp\www\lightbulb_edison/../_content/layouts/themes/ . $theme_name . /" directory does not exist.' ````

Comment: `echo` is not meant for joining variables. And `<?php` is pointless within a string or expression. And your `theme_name` is a constant too, not a variable.

Comment: Add the whole error message to the question please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786279/can-i-use-string-concatenation-to-define-a-class-const-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `(.)` for concatenation in php . like below..

```
define("theme_name", "andrew");
define("LAYOUT_DIR", ROOT_DIR.'_content/layouts/themes/'.theme_name.'/');
```

Or you can do this by using variable like this..

```
define("theme_name", "andrew");
$theme_name = theme_name;
define("LAYOUT_DIR", ROOT_DIR.'_content/layouts/themes/'.$theme_name.'/');
```

Answer (score 2):

In php the concatenation operator is **DOT(.)**

If you define a variable in php like following

```
define("theme_name", "andrew");
```

Then you have to use the variable like below

```
define("LAYOUT_DIR", ROOT_DIR. '_content/layouts/themes/'. theme_name . '/');
```