# Script PHP Error Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This PHP script works fine in Windows but in Linux has following error:

> Error: **syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';'**

Any idea what could be wrong?

```
 const LOGO_PATH    = 'notafiscal'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'logos'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
 const LOGO_PATHTMP = self::LOGO_PATH.'tmp'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
```

Comment: What is your `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` value?

Comment: @MaxZoom It's a PHP OS-dependent constant

Comment: Most likely your PHP version on Linux is different. See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786279/can-i-use-string-concatenation-to-define-a-class-const-in-php

Comment: As in, prior to PHP 5.6, you can't have complex `const` expressions.

Comment: Try to use `define("SEP", "/")` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated PHP Version of my vps.