# Internal Server Error with Endroid/Qrcode and __DIR__ const on Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, qr-code

i'm using endroid Qrcode bundle for creation of Qrcode object. I have an critical error because the QRCode object (https://github.com/endroid/QrCode/blob/master/src/QrCode.php) in this bundle use this constant. If i modify the source of the QRCode all works fine, but obviusly that is not a good solution. Why i have this bug on symfony? How can I fix it? 
This my error

```
Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';'
500 Internal Server Error - FatalErrorException
```

And this is the bundle: https://github.com/endroid/QrCode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason would be the PHP version of your current server: if you do have a version of PHP below 5.6, concatenation in a constant is not allowed by PHP.   It is allowed only as of **PHP 5.6.0**

> **Note**: 
>   Constant expression support was added in PHP 5.6.0.

source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php#example-185

Related answer from SO that got me there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36693544/2123530

Comment: I've just upgrade php of the my virtual machine (vagrant) to php 5.6.30 for run that bundle. What can i would wrong?

Comment: Apache not loading the upgraded php.so module yet ? Keep in mind also that you could have a different version of PHP client side or apache side. You can confirm that via Symfomy debug bar that should provide you a PHP version from apache side.

Comment: this can be my case, also when i launch my test in phpunit all works well, i can see that error only when I test manually my webapp. So, how can I check the version of php on apache side on my vagrant virtual machine?

Comment: The easiest since you are on Symfony is to click on your Symfony debugging bar, then from the left hand menu go into _Configuration_. Another way is to simply create a dummy php file that would read `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and access it.

Comment: ok, that is the problem, php on my symfony bar is 5.5.9. But I update php on my vagrant machine at 5.6.30 and if i run php -v on vagrant machine i see php at 5.6.30. What I'm not understanding? I'm using symfony 2.7.27. Why php on my symfony bar are different from my virtual machine? I presumed that wuold be the same php. What i'll do to fix?

Comment: You have to edit your apache configuration to use that new PHP version. Most likely you should look at /etc/apache2/https.conf. There look for a the PHP module loaded (a .so file) and adapt it to point to your updated PHP version.

Comment: ok, my problem was about configuration of vagrant machine, now all works fine. Remain the doubt for me about the phpUnit test run OK when the application not, maybe phpUnit use a different configuration of PHP? Otherwise thaks for the help ;)